# How to get maven dependencies as a single resolved artifact using aether?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, aether

I am using Aether to resolve dependencies for maven artifacts in a java project. I want to find the direct dependencies (without transitives) and want them as a single resolved artifact.

If using shrinkwrap I would do something like

```
Resolver.resolve(mavenArtifact).withoutTransitivity().asSingleResolvedArtifact();
```

I have the following for find the dependents without transitivity

```
RepositorySystem repoSystem = newRepositorySystem();
                RepositorySystemSession session = newSession( repoSystem );
                Artifact artifact = new DefaultArtifact(serviceJar.getCoordinate() );


                        ArtifactDescriptorRequest descriptorRequest = new ArtifactDescriptorRequest();
                        descriptorRequest.setArtifact( artifact );
                        descriptorRequest.setRepositories(new ArrayList<RemoteRepository>( Arrays.asList( newCentralRepository() ) ));
                        ArtifactDescriptorResult descriptorResult = repoSystem.readArtifactDescriptor( session, descriptorRequest );
                        descriptorResult.getDependencies();

                        }
private static RepositorySystem newRepositorySystem()
{
    DefaultServiceLocator locator = MavenRepositorySystemUtils.newServiceLocator();
    locator.addService( RepositoryConnectorFactory.class, BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory.class );
    locator.addService( TransporterFactory.class, FileTransporterFactory.class );
    locator.addService( TransporterFactory.class, HttpTransporterFactory.class );

    return locator.getService( RepositorySystem.class );
}

private static RepositorySystemSession newSession( RepositorySystem system )
{
    DefaultRepositorySystemSession session = MavenRepositorySystemUtils.newSession();
    LocalRepository localRepo = new LocalRepository( "/tmp" );
    session.setLocalRepositoryManager( system.newLocalRepositoryManager( session, localRepo ));
    return session;
}
public static List<RemoteRepository> newRepositories( RepositorySystem system, RepositorySystemSession session )
{
    return new ArrayList<RemoteRepository>( Arrays.asList( newCentralRepository() ) );
}

private static RemoteRepository newCentralRepository()
{
    return new RemoteRepository.Builder( "central", "default", "http://central-repo/" ).build();
}
```

So this gives me a list of all dependencies. How can I get a single jar of these dependencies?
How can this be achieved using Aether?
IS there a documentation on how these two libraries differ from  each other? In other words, what is the equivalent of 'MavenResolvedartifact'( as in shrinkwrap )in Aether? So that I can then use raw java to convert it into a single jar?

Comment: First if you are in java project from where did you got the RepositorySystem*, *Session* ?

Comment: I followed this example from the eclipse documentation https://github.com/eclipse/aether-demo/tree/master/aether-demo-snippets/src/main/java/org/eclipse/aether/examples. Where the example uses the local maven repo to create a session. Is this the recommended way?

Comment: What not using a maven build to create jar which contains the needed artifacts? I don't see the need to implement this in Java directly...I assume you are writing things for an integration tests...BTW: The example uses hard coded locations in the Booter.java class and does not take care of things like configuration in settings.xml etc.

Comment: No I am writing code to extract jars from these dependencies. So I need to have the metadata for a single artifact as a single jar which can then be processed and extracted for a jar.